# An SQL problem, there are multiple products in an order

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

An SQL problem, there are multiple products in an order. You want to query all order information including product a, product B, and product C. Thank you very much for your help
database:oracle 
Order Details

```
orderNo  goods 
1001     A
1001    B
1001     C
1001     D
1002    A
1003     A1
1003    B1
1003     C
1003     D
1004    A
```

…………
How can I find 1001?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: `SELECT goods FROM Order WHERE orderNo = 1001` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT ORDERNO
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE
    GOODS IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY ORDERNO
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GOODS) = 3
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select order_no
from order_details
where goods in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by order_no
having count(*) = 3
```

If the same `goods` may appear more than once for a given `order_no`, then you need `having count(distinct goods) = 3` instead of `having count(*) = 3`.